# Python data structure to contain only unique arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create Python data structure to contain only unique arrays of integers with different sizes. Order matters. Similar interface to Set: add, remove,...

```
a = [[2, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2]]

result = [[2, 0, 2],
    [2, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: yes, order matters

Comment: The answer you've accepted doesn't really implement a data structure. (There's no `add` or `remove`.)

Comment: What did you do to implement it, what is your problem? Where is a [mre]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't want to change the order of your result, try to use(python 3.6+):

```
list(map(list, dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, a)).keys()))
```

result:

```
[[2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2]]
```

Comment: Don't you mean `dict.fromkeys`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I think there is not much difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert each sublist to a tuple, convert the list of tuples to a set, and then convert the tuples back to lists and the set to a list, too:

```
list(map(list, set(map(tuple, a))))
#[[2, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```